# convert ages to groups of age ranges getting (ValueError: Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges)

Tags: python, pandas

My data frame includes ages from 0 to 87 and I'm trying to convert ages to age groups but I get the following error:

```
bins = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]
labels=['0-9','10-19','20-29','30-39','40-49','50-59','60-69','70-79','80-89']
df['bins'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

Error

```
ValueError: Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges
```

Comment: bins = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80, `90`] ?

Comment: yes it's working, why adding 90 ?

Comment: your label has `80-89` but in youe `bins` where is above 80?

Comment: You've provided 9 edges, meaning 8 bins (one for each connected pair of edges). So you can only have 8 labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've provided 9 edges, meaning 8 bins (one for each connected pair of edges). So you can only have 8 labels. Edited the bins

```
bins = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
labels=['0-9','10-19','20-29','30-39','40-49','50-59','60-69','70-79','80-89']
df['bins'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
```